# Does mailto support html for body?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating an asp.net/vb.net web app. I'm pulling alot of data from the db which will help populate an HTML mailto link I'm creating. The problem is, I'd like to have some HTML in the body, such as bold, italics, hyperlink, etc... Is this possible? If not, any suggestions on how to handle this using mailto? Or is my only alternative to use the built in asp.net mail functions?

Answer (score 0):

are you asking how to make a mailto link in html using asp? if so this is a code snipplet of mailto in asp/html? sorry i'm a little confused on what you are asking. asp is just a active server page so it supports html if thats what you are asking.

```
<a href = "mailto:abc@abc.com">abc@abc.com</a>
```

Comment: In your mailto link I know you can supply a subject and body. In the body portion can you somehow put html (even encoded somehow)? Such as "body='<b>Title</b><i>Italics</i>'", etc....

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tutorial at: http://www.addressmunger.com/mailto_syntax_tutorial/

Most mailto options have sort of crept in over the years, but it's completely up to the mail client vendor. Each browser also has a different limit to the length of the querystring so you have to be careful. Essentially, don't rely it for many complicated options and if you need well-formatted HTML emails it's better to create them on the server instead of the client.